# Set trustworthy property on Azure SQL db

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I'm trying to set trustworthy property on Azure SQL database:

```
ALTER DATABASE foodonline SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
```

and get this error:

[image: error]

How\where can i change permission in azure. 
p.s in local DB this query works good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this operation the user needs a fixed server role: `sysadmin`, which is only available on SQL Server database engines running on-premises or installed on an Azure Virtual Machine by you.

But you cannot run this command on a SQL Azure that is used as a Service because you will not have sysadmin role on the server that the SQL Azure is running on.

Security Center for SQL Server Database Engine and Azure SQL Database:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510589.aspx

Comment: Ok. But i need to add some pics to my database. I'm trying this [code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90254390/snip_20151226213303.png). And i get this message: You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement. I thought that this is because of the trustworthy property or not? p.s in local db this code works fine

Comment: I'm afraid openrowset is not supported in SQL Azure either. take a look at this link for other options for streaming Blobs to and from SQL Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/nb-no/blog/streaming-blobs-to-and-from-sql-azure/